# encrypt data sent to php web service

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I have a system which uses an iphone interface for data input. This data is sent to a php application layer in JSON format. The php data is then posted to the remote MYSQL database.

There seems to be some vulnerability to the data transmission:

1) The data is sent from the iPhone interface to the PHP application in cleartext using the HTTP POST request

2) The data can be sniffed server-side when the data is transmitted from the php file to the MYSQL database.

I was looking to get an insight from experienced members of the forum in how best to tackle the above issues and what particular frameworks if any exist to prevent any data attacks...

Answer (score 2):

1. Use HTTPS.

   Since it’s arguably the most widely-used encryption technology, it’s secure, well-documented, easy to set up on the server, and a one-letter change in the iPhone app.
2. MySQL [has built-in support for SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-connections.html) encryption, [which PHP supports](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php).

---

Edit, in response to ucabdro’s comment:

I would highly recommend taking a look at the [PCI DSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard), the security standards followed by companies which handle credit cards. They cover every aspect of data security, from physical security to database encryption. The standards themselves are available for free [at the standards council’s website](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/).

Not all of the standards may be relevant to you, but they serve as a good target.

Answer (score 1):

In step (1), if you can use https instead of http you can avoid sniffing of this communication.

Regarding (2), how much of an issue is this? Are you concerned because you are on a shared server? If someone has access to the server, would they not have access to both the DB and your file?

Comment: It's an issue because the system must be secure in all areas. If there is potential for data to be sniffed, preventative measures must be implemented...that's a specific requirment

Comment: @ucabdro It may be worth taking a look at the PCI DSS — standards followed by the payment card industry.